# Traceback from tkinter when I try to draw game board

Tags: python, tkinter

The folloing is the traceback from the tkinter when I draw the game board for Othello game.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SYN/Desktop/o_game.py", line 16, in <module>
    start.display_board(gamestate)
  File "C:/Users/SYN/Desktop\o_gui.py", line 131, in display_board
    self.draw_board(gamestate)
  File "C:/Users/SYN/Desktop\o_gui.py", line 145, in draw_board
    columnspan = 3)
  File "F:\PYTHON\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
```

_tkinter.TclError: ambiguous option "-col": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

The following is the related codes for drawing board.

```
def draw_board(self, gamestate):
    '''draw the game board, ready to resize'''
    self.gamestate = gamestate
    self.rows = gamestate.row
    self.cols = gamestate.col
    self.Ocanvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._root_window,
                                 width = 600, height = 600,
                                 background = 'pink')

    self.Ocanvas.grid(row = 1, col = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10,
                     sticky = tkinter.N + tkinter.S + tkinter.E + tkinter.W,
                     columnspan = 3)

    self.Ocanvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_canavs_clicked)
    self.Ocanvas.bind('<Configure>', self.on_canvas_resized)

    self._root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self._root_window.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
    self._root_window.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1)
    self._root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self._root_window.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
```

It seems that there are some problems with the step self.canvas.grid. But what's wrong with it?

Comment: It tells you the problem. Use `column = 0` instead of `col = 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot. XD

Comment: @StevenSummers Please post your answer in the answer section and not in this comment section.